# How can I reorder the data in my list SwiftData?

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I understand that we can sort and order directly in @Query, however I'm trying to implement a feature to allow user to manually sort using List (in edit mode)

```
@Query(sort: \FavouriteCommunity.order) private var favouriteCommunities: [FavouriteCommunity]

List {
    Section("Top communities") {
        // Some other views
    }
    Section("Favorites") {
        ForEach(favouriteCommunities) { item in
            NavigationLink(value: item) {
                FavouriteCommunityCellView(item: item)
            }
        }
        .onMove { from, to in
            favouriteCommunities.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'favouriteCommunities' is a get-only property

I can actually edit the item in FavouriteCommunityCellView(item: item) when I use @Bindable so I'm aware editing is possible on the object level. It seems that query is unable to be mutated, so curious if anyone have any suggestion on how to create a re-order feature on top of SwiftData. Thanks!

Comment: What is `order`?  You have to modify this attribute in each record to get the items reordered.

Comment: First of all you need a property on your model that holds the order, do you have that?

Comment: Hi Joakim, I do have a .order which holds an Int. But I have no idea how to write the new order to SwiftData. Would love some help here. Thank you.

Comment: You just update the `.order` property with a new value and SwiftData should take care of recording the results and updating the `favouriteCommunities`. I see how calculating new order values might be difficult in case of multiple items being moved, perhaps, make another `Array` from the `favouriteCommunities`, perform reordering on in (there is a built-in `move(fromOffset:,toOffset:)` method for that in `Array`) and use the indices of this new array to update `.order` values?